# RHEL 7.9 cannot register with subscription-manager

Tags: redhat-enterprise-linux, subscription

We have been using Red Hat [free developer subscription](https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2016/03/31/no-cost-rhel-developer-subscription-now-available/) for years, and everything is so far, so good.

However, the testing virtual machine popped an error saying the OS is missing updates because there is no valid subscription.

So, I used the commands in the below screenshot, trying to refresh the subscription on the virtual machine. All the Red Hat account login credentials are correct, and the portal shows 8 virtual machines registered under the current account, so it is within the limit. However, the command got an error `Unable to find available subscriptions for all your installed products.` , and the registration was unsuccessful.

The virtual machine's OS is Red Hat 7.9, though. We have this testing virtual machine because our production environment is still on this version.

So, we wonder what the culprit in this subscription issue might be. And we highly appreciate any hints and suggestions.

**The screenshot of command history:**

```
[root@hostname logs]# subscription-manager clean
All local data removed
[root@hostname logs]# subscription-manager register --auto-attach
Registering to: subscription.rhsm.redhat.com:443/subscription
Username: my.name@my.company.com
Password: 
The system has been registered with ID: 2xxxxxx0-fxxx-4xxx-axxx-7xxxxxxxxxxc
The registered system name is: hostname.local.example.com
Installed Product Current Status:
Product Name: Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server
Status:       Not Subscribed

Unable to find available subscriptions for all your installed products.
[root@hostname logs]# hostnamectl
   Static hostname: hostname.local.example.com
         Icon name: computer-vm
           Chassis: vm
        Machine ID: 9xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxd
           Boot ID: 6xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx0
    Virtualization: kvm
  Operating System: Red Hat Enterprise Linux
       CPE OS Name: cpe:/o:redhat:enterprise_linux:7.9:GA:server
            Kernel: Linux 3.10.0-1160.81.1.el7.x86_64
      Architecture: x86-64
[root@hostname logs]# cat /etc/redhat-release 
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.9 (Maipo)
[root@hostname logs]#
```

Comment: It probably has something to do with Redhat’s lifecycle on RHEL 7. I would contact Redhat with regards to your question. When you go to your developer account. Does it show you have an active license. They can be renewed but you must do that manually. Verify the VM can access Redhat’s servers.

Answer (score 1):

We tried the below two operations, and the issue disappeared. So, we don't know which change was directly effective, but we registered the OS.

- In the context of "Red Hat Account Portal > Systems", there used to be 8 systems of type "Virtual System", so we removed all of them.
- During the previous attempts, we left a window open for the graphic user interface of subscription management (command `subscription-manager-gui`), so we closed the window.

Then, we called the commands `subscription-manager clean` and `subscription-manager register --auto-attach` in a terminal and it worked as expected.

Comment: For me, running the `clean` and `register` commands was enough.